# Nested regex in $lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So I have two collections 'albums' and 'artists'. I created $lookup query, for finding info about artist based on their id in album docs. It is simple query and look just like this:

```
 Album.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            name: {$regex : myAlbumRegex, $options: 'i'}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "artists",
            "localField": "idArtist",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            as: "artist"
        }       
    }
```

This works just fine. But now I want to do regex on artists names that I found. I tried to use 'pipeline', but it doesn't seems to work. There's the code:

```
 Album.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            name: {$regex : myAlbumRegex, $options: 'i'}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "artists",
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { name: {$regex : myAuthorRegex, $options: 'i'} } },
                { $project: { _id: 0, data: { name: "$name" } } },
                { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
            ],
            as: "artist"
        }       
    }
```

Does anybody know what I should change in order for this to work?

Comment: No pipeline needed. You can use `Album.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            name: {$regex : myAlbumRegex, $options: 'i'}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "artists",
            "localField": "idArtist",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            as: "artist"
        }       
    }, {"$unwind":"$artist"},{ $match: { "artist.name": {$regex : myAuthorRegex, $options: 'i'} } }]`. You can use `$group` at the end to bring back the author documents into album.
`

Comment: Lookup pipeline not needed but just for demonstration. Something like `{
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "albums",
           let: { idArtist: "$idArtist"},
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                   { $eq: [ "$_id",  "$$idArtist" ] }
                 }
              },
              { $match: { name: {$regex : myAuthorRegex, $options: 'i'} } },
              { $project: { _id: 0, data: { name: "$name" } } },
              { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
           ],
           as: "artist"
         }
    }`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you!